# pandas: select all rows matching multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

i have the following dataframe:

```
 >>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 1], 'col2': [6, 3, 6]})
 >>> df
    col1  col2
  0     1     6
  1     2     3
  2     1     6
```

and the following dictionary:

```
 >>> di = {'col1': 1, 'col2': 6}
 >>> di
 {'col2': 6, 'col1': 1}
```

i am looking for a solution that will iterate through **di** and find the matching rows in **df**.  i do not want to write a line that uses the column names and values specifically.  i have seen those solutions on the forum, and that is not what i am trying to do here.  the (terrible non-)solution i had going was:

```
 is_not_first = True
 tf_series = None
 for key, val in di.iteritems():
      if is_not_first:
           tf_series = (tf_series & (df[key] == val))
      else:
           tf_series = (df[key] == val)
           is_not_first = False
```

i plan to use **tf_series** to set another column in **df** later with:

```
 df.loc[tf_series, 'col3'] = True
```

judging from many of the excellent pandas posts i have seen i am sure there is something much more concise, not to mention, something that actually works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine all your logic into 1 line, and rather than building a redundant Series, you can build another DataFrame which has the same Index/Column with your **df** and assign to `df['col3']` directly, here is one way to achieve this:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 1], 'col2': [6, 3, 6]})

In [3]: di = {'col1': 1, 'col2': 6}

In [4]: df['col3'] = pd.DataFrame([df[k]==v for k,v in di.iteritems()]).all()

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   col1  col2   col3
0     1     6   True
1     2     3  False
2     1     6   True
```

Or a faster and shorthanded version using **map**:

```
In [6]: df['col3'] = pd.DataFrame(map(lambda k: df[k]==di[k], di)).all()
```

---

### Breakdown explanation

If you look at the **list**, when you iterate the dictionary **di**, it will give you **key/value** pairs, which in fact are the columns/values of your original **df**.
So `df[column]` will give you its value, and you compare that with dictionary's **v**, it yields **True/False**.

```
In [8]: [df[k]==v for k,v in di.iteritems()]
Out[8]: 
[0     True
 1    False
 2     True
 Name: col2, dtype: bool, 0     True
 1    False
 2     True
 Name: col1, dtype: bool]
```

---

Then you construct a shadow DataFrame from that results, will give you this:

```
pd.DataFrame([df[k]==v for k,v in di.iteritems()])
Out[9]: 
         0      1     2
col2  True  False  True
col1  True  False  True
```

---

#### Edit

As @ant pointed, I've incorrectly used **any()** whereas it should be **all()** to satisfy all `True` values:

Finally, **all()** which return **index/result** which above column(s) satisfy  ALL **True** condition:

```
In [10]: pd.DataFrame([df[k]==v for k,v in di.iteritems()]).all()
Out[10]: 
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

And you just need to assign this result column to `df['col3']`, and you're done.

To avoid `SettingWithCopy` warning, you just need to break the one liner into 2:

```
new_col = pd.DataFrame(df[k]==v for k,v in di.iteritems()).all()
df['col3'] = new_col
```

Comment: this works great!  however, i am getting a warning associated with this line.  any idea how to clear this up?                                    SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @ant, I have edited the answer to show you how, it's basically breaking the one-liner into 2 lines, because it warns you not to modifying the **df** while accessing part of the value in it. Just like this: `new_col = pd.DataFrame(df[k]==v for k,v in di.iteritems()).any()`, 
`df['col3'] = new_col`

Comment: doesn't seem to work on the following:
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [6,7], 'c2': ['93594eb50db198478f2e0214572f2560','d16154eaacbc7b19f1c5e8cafda1e1a6'], 'c3': [dateutil.parser.parse('2014-10-02 12:52:11'),dateutil.parser.parse('2014-10-02 12:52:11')], 'c4': [3,3], 'c5': [809,809], 'c6': [336,335]})
>>> di1 = {'c1': 6, 'c2': '93594eb50db198478f2e0214572f2560', 'c3': dateutil.parser.parse('2014-10-02 12:52:11'), 'c4': 3, 'c5': 809, 'c6': 336}
>>> di2 = {'c1': 7, 'c2': 'd16154eaacbc7b19f1c5e8cafda1e1a6', 'c3': dateutil.parser.parse('2014-10-02 12:52:11'), 'LogFile_id': 3, 'c5': 809, 'c6': 335}

Comment: changing any to all fixes the issue, as all conditions must be satisfied for the entire row to match.  i'll mark answer as correct after edited.  thanks again!

Comment: @ant, you're correct, I have incorrectly used **any()** whereas all **True** should be **all()**. Thanks for pointing this out ;)