# How to use a conditional statement based on DataFrame boolean value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Now I know how to check the dataframe for specific values across multiple columns. However, I cant seem to work out how to carry out an if statement based on a boolean response.

For example:

Walk directories using `os.walk` and read in a specific file into a dataframe.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(main):
        filters = '*specificfile.csv'
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filters):
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, filename),error_bad_lines=False)
```

Now checking that dataframe across multiple columns. The first value being the column name (column1), the next value is the specific value I am looking for in that column(banana). I am then checking another column (column2) for a specific value (green). If both of these are true I want to carry out a specific task. However if it is false I want to do something else.

so something like:

```
if (df['column1']=='banana') & (df['colour']=='green'):
    do something
else: 
    do something
```

Comment: What is the specific task? is it to update something in the same row?

Comment: Are you wanting to check whether any rows satisfy your condition for a df or rows?

Comment: I do not see any question in you question.

Comment: No i dont want to carry out any modifications to the data. There are plenty of comprehension style statements on google based on modifying the data. But I cant seem to find any with a just a normal `if`. We can assume the task will be a system based command action; `os.makdirs` for example

Comment: Apologies Alex.S I will modify it to try make myself clearer. Ive just reread that a few times and I can see the question in two forms. 1. In words, 'I cant seem to work out how to carry out an if statement based on a boolean response.' the 2nd is in code form (the snippet at the bottom of the post).

Comment: @iNoob do you want to check row by row? Or in any row in the complete df contains that value/s ?

Comment: Anard S Kumar, checking the values is not the problem. Im doing that fine and getting the responses i would expect. `(df['column1']=='banana') & (df['colour']=='green')` returns true, however what I am asking is how do I create an if statement based on its response.

Comment: `if (df['column1']=='banana') & (df['colour']=='green').any():` ?

Comment: that expression should return a series of true/false values, you want to check whether any one of them is true or not right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90307/discussion-between-inoob-and-anand-s-kumar).

Comment: Do you mean [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973890/pandas-select-all-rows-matching-multiple-conditions)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to check if any row of the DataFrame meets your conditions you can use [`.any()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) along with your condition . Example -

```
if ((df['column1']=='banana') & (df['colour']=='green')).any():
```

Example -

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6

In [17]: ((df['A']==1) & (df['B'] == 2)).any()
Out[17]: True
```

This is because your condition - `((df['column1']=='banana') & (df['colour']=='green'))` - returns a Series of True/False values.

This is because in pandas when you compare a series against a scalar value, it returns the result of comparing each row of that series against the scalar value and the result is a series of True/False values indicating the result of comparison of that row with the scalar value. Example -

```
In [19]: (df['A']==1)
Out[19]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: A, dtype: bool

In [20]: (df['B'] == 2)
Out[20]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

And the `&` does row-wise `and` for the two series. Example -

```
In [18]: ((df['A']==1) & (df['B'] == 2))
Out[18]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Now to check if any of the values from this series is True, you can use [`.any()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) , to check if all the values in the series are True, you can use [`.all()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html) .

Comment: Great, thanks Anand S Kumar. Can I ask how you worked that out? I didnt see anything in docs that explained that

Comment: Update the answer with a small explanation.