# Pandas conditional filter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
   A     B     C
0  True  True  True
1  True  False False
2  False False False
```

I would like to add a row D with the following conditions:

D is true, if A, B and C are true. Else, D is false.

I tried

```
df['D'] = df.loc[(df['A'] == True) & df['B'] == True & df['C'] == True]
```

I get

```
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

Then I tried to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713221/how-to-use-a-conditional-statement-based-on-dataframe-boolean-value-in-pandas) and wrote a similar function as suggested in the link:

```
def all_true(row):

   if row['A'] == True:
      if row['B'] == True:
         if row['C'] == True:
             val = True
   else:
      val = 0

return val

df['D'] = df.apply(all_true(df), axis=1)
```

In which case I get

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I'd appreciate suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or even better:

```
df['D']=df.all(1)
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
       A      B      C      D
0   True   True   True   True
1   True  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 5):

Comparing with `True` is not necessary, ony chain boolean masks with `&`:

```
df['D'] = df['A'] & df['B'] & df['C']
```

If performance is important:

```
df['D'] = df['A'].values & df['B'].values & df['C'].values
```

Or use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check all `True`s per rows:

```
df['D'] = df[['A','B','C']].all(axis=1)

#numpy all 
#df['D'] = np.all(df.values,1)
```

---

```
print (df)
       A      B      C      D
0   True   True   True   True
1   True  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False
```

**Performance**:

[image: g]

```
np.random.seed(125)

def all1(df):
    df['D'] = df.all(axis=1)
    return df

def all1_numpy(df):
    df['D'] = np.all(df.values,1)
    return df

def eval1(df):
    df['D'] = df.eval('A & B & C')
    return df

def chained(df):
    df['D'] = df['A'] & df['B'] & df['C']
    return df

def chained_numpy(df):
    df['D'] = df['A'].values & df['B'].values & df['C'].values
    return df
```

---

```
def make_df(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.choice([True, False], size=n),
                       'B':np.random.choice([True, False], size=n),
                       'C':np.random.choice([True, False], size=n)})
    return df

perfplot.show(
    setup=make_df,
    kernels=[all1, all1_numpy, eval1,chained,chained_numpy],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(2, 25)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=False,
    xlabel='len(df)')
```

Comment: @jezrael, what is `perfplot` is this matplotlib import? i'm  into that learning this is good example.

Comment: no, it is custom module, learning from unutbu, https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot - but it use matplotlib

Answer (score 2):

Using pandas [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html#pandas.DataFrame.eval):

```
df['D'] = df.eval('A & B & C')
```

Or:

```
df = df.eval('D = A & B & C')
#alternative inplace df.eval('D = A & B & C', inplace=True)
```

Or:

```
df['D'] = np.all(df.values,1)

print(df)
       A      B      C      D
0   True   True   True   True
1   True  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False
```