# Sinuous data aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I am usimg pandas to get statictics of users activitY:

```
    import pandas as pd
    dataset = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/data.csv')
    # data is a table with columns: src_id, time, requests    
    # time - represents time slots(30 s), when client was active 

    g = dataset.groupby("src_ip")
    clients_statistic = pd.DataFrame(columns=["requests_count", "max_requests_in_30s", "time_slots_count"])

    clients_statistic.active_time_slots_count = g["time"].count()
    clients_statistic.requests_count = g["requests"].sum()
    clients_statistic.max_requests_in_30s = g["requests"].max()
```

I already have value of maximum activity. Now i need to get moment of time, when user activity was max. I can get it by iterating. Byt i don't think that iterating - is a good idea.

Comment: look for `maxarg`

Answer (score 0):

For that you could use simple condition

E.g. you have value **max_value** for specific user with some **src_user_ip**.

To find the moments of time, when this user has maximum activity just find:

```
data[(data['src_id'] == src_user_ip) && (data['requests'] == max_value)]
```

> Condition inside the squared parentheses gonna produce True/False mask, that will be used to get the information that you wanna to find.

> You can read more about the pandas conditions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713221/how-to-use-a-conditional-statement-based-on-dataframe-boolean-value-in-pandas)

Comment: Could you compare your solution with my?

Comment: @paladovalex yes, it's probably gonna work too. The only problem is that there are sorting that is not required. With such a conditions you are able to write a lot of stuff too.

Answer (score 0):

it was not as difficult as I first thought

```
g = dataset.sort_values(by="requests", ascending=False).groupby("src_ip")
clients_statistic.time_slots_count = g["time"].count()
clients_statistic.requests_count = g["requests"].sum()
clients_statistic.max_requests_in_30s = g["requests"].first()
clients_statistic.max_requests_moment = g["time"].first()
```