# Return a value/function if Pandas Dataframe contains speicific value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe and I want to return a value (or a function) if a specific value is found in the DataFrame.

I have looked everywhere and all I could mostly [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713221/how-to-use-a-conditional-statement-based-on-dataframe-boolean-value-in-pandas) is if the value is found, then it will return either True or False. And most of the search results pointed to similar answers.

The True or False is helpful to go in the right direction, but what I want to ultimately do  would be something like

```
if a.values == 'abc': 
     function()
```

or something like

```
if a.values == 'abc':
     plt.imgplot(a.png)
```

Comment: Try this `if (df.to_numpy() == 'abc'):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a for loop and check for your condition:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[1,2,3]})
for val in df.values:
    if val == 1:
        plt.imgplot(df)
```

Comment: This actually helped. Thanks. I instead used a df.values.tolist() method and then used that in the for loop.

Comment: You're welcome – glad my answer helped!